# Can a global variable defined in a one file in anyting.php used in different file someting.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

is there any possibility of any variable defined in a php file in WordPress, that it can be used in another file?

Comment: Yes, you can use

Comment: but how please give me an example if possible.
A bunch of code will help alot

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: i think it should also be noted that you should try not to use the global scope unless you absolutely have to. You don't really want your code to be that tightly coupled.

Comment: So long as the variable is outside a function or class it's automatically considered global. It's also global if it is declared global in a function. Then you can use it in another php file as well.

Comment: It has created a bit of confusion @KarloKokkak
there is no need of including the 1st file then?
or should i use it?

Comment: You have to include the file containing the global variable to the file you want the variable to be used at.

Comment: Thank you karlo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the file with the defined variable in the second file, like this:

anything.php:

```
$var= 'test';
```

something.php:

```
include 'anything.php'; 
echo $var;
```

Comment: Thanks!
can i use require as well in same case?

Comment: can you help me answering a question related to metabox in wordpress?

Comment: sure, whats the quesiton/link to the question?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298364/how-can-i-add-a-metabox-to-pull-list-of-custom-posts-any-two-on-edit-or-add-po/298372

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use global var on WordPress like as usual doing on PHP like below

**from.php**

```
global $id;
$id = 10;
```

**to.php**

```
global $id;
echo $id;
```

Edit:
As we discussed on the comment using classes is a good way.

**demo1.php**

```
class test{
    public $i = 10;
    public $j = 20;
    public $k = 30;
}
```

**demo2.php**

```
$obj = new test();
echo $obj->i;
echo $obj->j;
echo $obj->k;
```

Comment: what will be the case if no global was used in to.php ?

Comment: What do you mean if no global was used?

Comment: if no global $id; was used in to.php?
what will it print?

Comment: This is not necessarily complete. The crucial part is that `to.php` needs to either directly or indirectly [include](https://php.net/manual/function.include.php) `from.php` or be included by it. Which could cause side-effects if done ignorantly.

Comment: It will throw warning undefined var $a

Comment: if form.php is include on to.php file. why you need to global define on to.php

Comment: yes you are correct, I meant should define global var on `form.php` before accessing on `to.php` otherwise it would be null

Comment: How to include?

Comment: No need to include just add your code flow to your question. its bit confusing how you trying to achieve this

Comment: there are two files
1. demo1.php
2. demo2.php

demo1.php has 
global $nimesh;
$nimesh = 10;

demo2.php has
echo $nimesh;

what should i do to print the one or may be any variable in demo1.php to demo2.php?
what is the best way of doing it?
should i use global variable or i should use include ?
how?

Comment: The best way is use classes. include file to use var is the worst way to do and also you need more than one var so global wont be good.

Comment: check my answer that may help you.

Comment: Thank You! as i am new to php.
i am looking to have good concept on it.

Comment: Good always use OOP , its best practice in PHP. Happy coding